# Why does the global thread_local variable not initialized as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, thread-local, thread-local-storage

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() : n(7)
    {}

    int n;
};

thread_local A a;

int main()
{
    cout << a.n << endl;
}
```

My compiler is clang 3.8 shipped with VS 2015.

To my surprise, the output is `0`, rather than `7` as expected.

Why does the main thread not call `A::A()` to initialize the `global thread_local` variable `a`?

Is it conforming to the C++ standard?

Comment: works for me: Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

Comment: Your code works in gcc 6.3 as well.

Comment: seems to be a bug of clang 3.8.

Comment: Check out this site for comparing results of different compilations. https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Just tested, it works pretty well with gnu++11 compiler. Output is 7

Comment: Also ok for g++ 6.2.0, 5.4.1 and 4.9.4

Comment: since you mention both clang and VS, this might actually be a bad interaction between clang and the link.exe since the linker is naturally also involved in initialization routines getting called